# Selenium and Python using If statement

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying understand why an `if else` isn't working using Selenium and Python. I have tried several different variations, but I believe this should work and stubbornly, maybe blindly, keep coming back to it.

example:

```
    if (self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('product')).text == "FEATURED PRODUCTS":
        print "\nHome Pass"
    else:
        print "\nHome Fail"
```

Tried this as well

```
if self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("product-teaser-list").text in "Featured Products":
```

Each execution returns `Fail` and when using assert, below, the `.text` is found. So I know the text is found with this method.

```
assert "FEATURED PRODUCTS" in self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('product').text
```

Comment: `==` is a different quest compared to `in` - the latter is substring like the former exact match ...

Comment: Replace `==` with `in`.

Comment: Thanks @Dilettant and @cdarke I tried that too and returns `fail` as well.

Comment: To build on what @Dilettant has said: the text node might contain more text than just "FEATURED PRODUCTS", like some empty space. Could you post the link of the page, if it exist?

Comment: Ah: You invoke the text attribute differently (there is a paren too much in the first case ;-)

Comment: Ok. I tried, what I believe you guys are instructing: `if self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-teaser-list').text in "FEATURED PRODUCTS":` with same `fail`

Comment: Apologies, @dasdachs I can't post the URL. Pre launch.

Comment: @Dave: no problem. I get it.

Comment: `"abc" == "abc"` is `True`. `"ab" == "abc"` is `False`. `"ab" in "abc"` is `True`. `"abc" in "ab"` is `False`. Obviously if matters what is on left side of operator and right side of operator when operator is `in`. Each of your _variations_ are entirely different operations and different results for each of them **are expected**.

Comment: Correct, @Rogalski. I went back to using `abc == abc` as this is what I need. However, the question still hangs, it returns `fail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this following code.

```
if "FEATURED PRODUCTS" in self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('product').text
```

If this isn't working try to debug that. something white space creates an issue. however given the assert statement is passing, following should work.

Comment: Worked. Only need to close the method with `:`